# VB.Net application - display a message to the user whilst the application is starting up

Tags: asp.net, jquery, css, vb.net, performance

I have recently created an application where a lot of data is loaded into objects when the application starts up, and other data as it is required. For example if the user requests the catalogue page then it will load all the top level category data into objects of type Category. This will then stay there to be used by other users (who will therefore not have to load this data into objects) and can be altered by admin if they happen to login during the same application instance. I know this is not the most efficient solution, as pointed out below, but it works and the page load, at the moment, is not too long. It is very quick if most of the required data is already loaded into objects. It is also tailored to the business' needs - unlike other techniques such as Linq-to-SQL.

The problem I am facing is when a page is requested which requires lots of data to be displayed about different types of object. For example when a catalogue page is requested which displays information on a product which can be bought, it then loads all the products and categories (as the products make reference to the category object, not just the category name).

I would like to display a loading symbol with a message whilst all this data is being loaded into objects, so the user knows its not just in a loop or anything. Is there any way to do this? I am open to using JS / jQuery if I need to.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Richard

PS I am working on ways to make it more efficient - such as using HashTables or HashMaps. However this is taking time as there are so many different types of item (News, Events, Catalogue Item - Range, Collection, Design, RangeCollection, CollectionDesign, RangeCollectionDesign and RangeDesign - Users, PageViews and the list goes on).

Comment: Hmm looks like I have actually found an answer. Think I must've missed this link when googling earlier. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/LoadingMsgWhilePageLoads.aspx. Will leave this question open regardless in case anyone has a better solution - maybe one that doesn't require JS.

Comment: You should almost certainly reconsider your design approach - use some lazy loading techniques so you only load things as they need to be presented to the user.  I'm unclear on how this data could be shared with other users, this is a web app, isn't it? That part sounds a bit dicey. But generally I think that using "please wait" things should be limited to them waiting for the server to do a job, not to load tons of possibly unneeded data on a page load (unless we're talking about a big flash thing or something). Your app shouldn't have to load so much if its not needed immediately.

Comment: I will make it so it simply loads the requested data over time. However at the moment this will have to do. I always knew that, using this approach, there would eventually be problems. Having looked at the data a bit since posting this, I think most of the data is actually page views, increasing by 50+ per day - so I could simply archive page views over a week old. That would solve the problem for this site. However I am thinking of doing a survey site which is a lot more usable than current ones, but the excessive data would, in this case, be the surveys and questions themselves.

Comment: Oh by the way all these survey sites that are around at the moment (or all the well known ones that I am joined up to) use a loading symbol, or a blank page. I don't think it would be overkill to use a loading symbol in the case of a new site. And in answer to your question, I can't remember the exact method I use to store the data across multiple users but I think I am using the Application object, for example `Application("SiteContent") = New SiteContent();`. Currently the Manager classes are only populated when they are first required. For example through `SiteContent.UserManager().Items`.

Comment: It just occurred to me that showing only the requested item (and therefore loading only the requested item into an object) wouldn't work as the menu displays all the categories. First, however, they system checks that there is more than one product in each category before displaying the link to the category - we don't want customers navigating to empty categories now, do we?

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but I do believe that Javascript is required in order to display a "loading" image...  Using server-side scriping alone would typically require an entire page load after all the content loads unless you want to start messing with IFrames.

This is a job for AJAX.  A common solution to your problem is to have a small page that displays a loading icon.  The page has some JavaScript that makes additional HTTP requests to the server to download the rest of the page.  JQuery has a "$.ajax" method that is designed to simplify this process.

I would suggest looking at the documentation to the .ajax method in the jQuery documentation.  Unfortunately, it seems to be a rather delicate process to get all the scripting code right and it takes a while to learn it all.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I don't think we want to make the site completely inaccessible to the 5% who have JavaScript turned off (based on the statistics for the last time I looked at W3Schools - in March / April). A lot of our customers are elderly business men / women - they tend to be people who run a single shop on a day to day basis and are not very technical. Non-technical folk tend to be a bit iffy about security, and therefore would probably believe anything they read about JS being insecure. There must be some solution where the page fires some JS when the request is first made...

Comment: Hmm on looking again at the link I posted in on my question, it would seem that those solutions are not good for this situation - one method uses the technique you suggested, the other one I am too tired to understand but it is certainly not simple. I don't know if there is a solution to this problem which is as simple as I wish it to be... Will work on it sometime over the next few weeks - too busy with job interviews and applications at the moment...